# How to write a filter with the MediaWiki AbuseFilter extension

Tags: filter, mediawiki

Hello there,

just a "quick" question - I already installed the mediawiki properly - same with the extension itself, all working properly.

The thing is that Mediawiki extension page (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AbuseFilter) won't tell me much about HOW to write a code for a filter, and google searches didn't return any valuable data like code block examples.

I'd be overjoyed if somebody could provide me a working code for the filter, even as simple as one for replacing typical f-bomb for the word "flowers", or whatever, since strReplace does nothing on it's own and I have no idea how to handle things.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official manual is [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:AbuseFilter/Rules_format). For real-life examples, just go to Special:AbuseFilter on a wiki that's using it and see the code of public filters. [For example, on English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:AbuseFilter).